# SSH, entered command but it didn't execute, can't type anything

Tags: bash, ssh

I used the command `tar -x file.tar.gz` and, for one reason or anything it failed. Then I get stuck being able to type anything in, but not being able to run any more commands. Pressing enter just gives me a new line. I don't know how to break out of it either (escape etc doesn't work). The only way I can get back working is to close putty and reconnect.

Is there a way to get it back to normal so I can keep going because it's irritating closing it all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try hitting CTRL+C :) This will cancel/kill/stop the running command!

But the best way to untar is to use -v to verbose the output :

```
tar -zxvf yourfile.tar.gz
```

With that, you'll perhaps see that your file just take more time than you thought unarchiving ;)

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl-C can be used to send a break to the executable that's hanging, but it's up to the application to handle it. Ctrl-Z will break you out of the running executable, but you'll need to then manually kill the process.

What you're doing wrong is you're not gunzipping the archive.

Try this

tar -zxf file.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

If you want to quit it, press CTRL+c.
If you want to keep it but being able to write more commands while it's working, press CTRL+z and bg.
Then it will work in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Your command failed because it is trying to read stdin.  This is because you never told it the name of the tar file with an "f" option.

Answer (score 0):

A good Idea would be to use [GNU screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen). That way, when a command hangs, you can open another screen and take a look at the system (e.g. top to see if tar is still working) or you could kill the process by pressing (strg+a) + k to hard-kill the running process within the screen-session.
Screen also has the nice feature that your processes keep running even though your SSH-connection died.  It's a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

Your tar invocation is waiting for input on the command line as the others pointed out. You may also use Ctrl-D to indicate EOF to the tar process.